# Using a user-installed python library

Tags: python, import

I am working on a machine that I do not have root access to. I have installed scikit-learn library just for my user account. The machine already has an old version of SciPy (version 0.7.2) installed. Many of SKLearn's features require a newer version of SciPy.

When I install a newer version of SciPy with easy_install --user, I still see the old version when I import it. Similarly, SKLearn still uses the old version of SciPy and fails to import using the --user flag.

```
easy_install -U --user scipy
```

Seems to install okay...

Now, inside of python:

```
import scipy
scipy.__version__
>  '0.7.2'

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
---> 23 from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr
     24
     25 from ..externals import six

ImportError: cannot import name lsqr
```

How do I use the correct version of SciPy?

Comment: Note that some python distributions, such as anaconda, can be installed as completely user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to adjust your $PATH or $PYTHONPATH setting. According to [the easy_install docs on the --user options](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#use-the-user-option) the installation occurs in site.USER_BASE.

So at the command line run `python -c "import site; print site.USER_BASE"` and then go to wherever it prints out to make sure your package is installed there. If it is you can add the following to your .bashrc for the future:

`export PYTHONPATH=$WHATEVER_WAS_JUST_PRINTED_OUT:$PYTHONPATH`

Comment: This helped! I was looking in the wrong area to find where the user library installed, and this helped me track it down. It turned out scipy hadn't installed.

Comment: Very minor comment, you don't need the $ in front of WHATEVER_WAS_JUST_PRINTED_OUT

Comment: Ah yeah that's just a generic way of derefrencing any variable (image we had saved the printed thing to WHATEVER_WAS_JUST_PRINTED_OUT), I can see why that's confusing though, sorry about that.